# Criar um menu com categorias

Tags: php, mysql, menu

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em PHP e MySQL, e gostaria de criar um menu que mostrasse as categorias cadastradas em um banco de dados.

No caso tenho duas tabelas relacionadas cujo nomes são `tbl_categorias` e `tbl_subcategorias`, que possuem os seguintes campos:

```
tbl_categoria

categoria_id | categoria
----------------------------
1            | Aço e Metais

===================================

tbl_subcategoria

subcategoria_id | subcategoria | categoria_fk
-----------------------------------------------
1               | Ferro        | 1
```

Como eu posso criar um menu (categorias) que contenha também um submenu (subcategorias) em PHP? A princípio estou tentando criar um código PHP para inseri-lo nas tags HTML abaixo:

```html
<ul>

<li></li>

</ul>
```

Como posso proceder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<ul>

<li></li>

</ul>
```

Você quer criar um menu e submenu com as categorias e subcategorias vindos do banco, dessa forma?

```
<?php
    // Conexão com o Banco (local)
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die(mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db($conexao, "nome_do_banco") or die(mysqli_error());
    mysqli_set_charset($conexao, 'utf8');

    // Busca as categorias do banco
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_categoria";
    $query = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $categoria_id = $row['categoria_id'];
        $categoria = $row['categoria'];
        ?>
        <ul>
            <li><?php echo $categoria ?> 
                <ul>
                    <?php
                    // Ainda dentro do laço while que buscou as categorias, busca-se as subcategorias passando o id de referência "fk" 
                    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_subcategoria WHERE categoria_fk = $categoria_id";
                    $query2 = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql2);
                    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {
                        $subcategoria = $row1['subcategoria'];
                    }
                    echo "<li>$subcategoria</li>";
                    ?>                            
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Deve existir outra forma mais "elegante" de se fazer isso, mas 
creio que esse deve funcionar.

Comment: Olá Julio. Obrigado pelo retorno. Irei implementar e ajustar o código acima conforme a minha necessidade. Valeu!